# How to update an element in an array?

Tags: java, arrays

How can I get the `Observation` method to increase a single element in the `numberofObs` array by `1`, every time I use it?

I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

```
public class Database {
    private ArrayList <String> databaseOfBirds = new ArrayList<String>();
    private int[] numberofObs = new int[databaseOfBirds.size()];

    public void add(String name, String latinName) {
        databaseOfBirds.add(name + "(" + latinName + ")"); 
    }

    public String Observation(String birdname){

        for(int i = 0; i < databaseOfBirds.size(); i++) {
            if(databaseOfBirds.get(i).contains(birdname)) {
                numberofObs[i]++; 
                return "";
            }   
        }
        return "Is not a bird!";
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `System.out.println(numberofObs[i]);`

Comment: sure you want to print numberofObs[0]?

Comment: I was trying to test my code hence I had that line, just removed it..

Comment: Your code of increasing `numberofObs[i]` is not wrong. The value of `numberofObs` is not set may be because the `if` statement is not reached. Please try to using debugger

Comment: `databaseOfBirds.size()` is `0`. That cause the problem

Comment: make sure you are aware that `contains` will perform a substring search. if you want to check if strings are the same, use `.equals()` or `.equalsIgnoreCase`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your numberofObs array it's length is zero, since at that point databaseOfBirds is empty. Unless you're growing the array in some unlisted code you'll get a NullPointerException the first time you find a bird.

You could fix this by making numberofObs a List:

```
private List<Integer> numberofObs = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then in your add method add the line:

```
numberofObs.add(0);
```

Finally, change

```
numberofObs[i]++;
```

to

```
numberofObs.set(i, 1 + numberofObs.get(i));
```

Answer (score 2):

Implementation is wrong in 2 places:

1. numberOfObs assignment will trigger ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException since you are not resizing it each time a new bird is added to database
2. you are not increasing anything on the matching bird counter

I am understanding you want to have a separate counter for each bird matched by Observation. Here you are (there are several approaches in terms of data structures, taking the one easiest to understand):

```
public class Database {
    private List<String> databaseOfBirds = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Integer> numberofObs = new ArrayLidt<>();

    public void add(String name, String latinName) {
        databaseOfBirds.add(name + "(" + latinName + ")"); 
        numberofObs.add(0);
    }

    public String Observation(String birdname){
        for(int i = 0; i < databaseOfBirds.size(); i++) {
            if (databaseOfBirds.get(i).contains(birdname)) {
                numberofObs.set(i, numberofObs.get(i)+1);
                System.out.println(numberofObs.get(i));
                return "";
            }   
        }
        return "Is not a bird!";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a Map instead of 2 Lists.

```
private Map<String, Long> birds = new HashMap<>();
```

Easier to manage. Unless memory is scarce, you probably don't want to use `int[]`.